# Splitting a URL by either of 2 different parts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, my code splits the URL and removes anything after `&7`. How can I also make it check for `|relevance` at the same time and split by whichever one it sees?

```
$(document).ready(($) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  if (params.has("query")) {
    const query = params.get("query").split('%7').pop();
    $("#textfield").val(query);
  }
});
```

I tried replacing
`.split('%7').pop();` with `.split('%7' || '|relevance').pop();` but that didn't work.

Comment: "_but that didn't work._" -> it is always a good idea to check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to see what will work. As it turns out, you can use a regular express to achieve your goal.

Comment: What is an example url? what is the expected output. Give us input and output

Answer (score 1):

The or needs to be in regex format.

here is where you can test regex:
https://regex101.com/r/kQwpTN/1

```
const query = params.get("query").split(/%7|\|relevance/).pop();
```

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this didn't work. I gets rid of the first part (`&7`) but not the second part (`|relevance`).

Comment: @rocket129083,  I am guessing it is a spelling error.  Try the link in the answer.  Put the urls you are testing in the test string box.  It might be something with spaces or escape characters.  Or add the urls you are testing to your question.

Comment: @rocket129083, it looks like I formatted the regex wrong too.  It should work now.